# Interpolation of function that includes a step change (discontinuous)

Tags: functions, interpolation, continuity

I have the following function that includes a step change:

[function image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju6Bj.png)

For those who cannot access the image, the function is linear between two times $t_1$ and $t_2$ with gradient $m_a$, there is a step-change at point $t_2$, then is linear between times $t_2$ and $t_3$ with gradient $m_b$. $t_1$ and $t_3$ have values $x_1$ and $x_3$, and for $t_2$: the start of the step-change is $x_{2a}$ and the end of the step change is $x_{2b}$.

The variables I know are: $t_1$, $t_2$, $t_3$, $x_1$, $x_3$, and the magnitude of the step change (ie. $(x_{2b} - x_{2a})$). I do not know the values of any other variables.

Are the degrees of freedom low enough so that interpolation (linear or any other type) is possible, or do I not know the values of enough variables? If it is possible, how?

Thanks.

Note: [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021904512000366) might hold the answer but it'll use language and symbols etc. that are way above my level.

EDIT: I should have noted: $m_a\neq m_b$

Comment: You need another $x$ value, for example $x_{2a}$. Otherwise you won't be able to write the line equations for both segments. Each requires two points: two time values and two corresponding $x$ values. You have enough time values, because $t_2$ belongs to both lines. If, however, you know at least one gradient (slope), you are set. If not, you need one more variable

Comment: Thanks, I feared as much. Is there a way to estimate it by iteration please?

Comment: In general, I doubt it. If you are certain that the gradients are different, then you can have a lot of possible values for $x_{2a}$. Imagine moving the vertical segment up and down, while keeping $x_1$ and $x_3$ fixed.

Comment: Either $x_2,$ $x_3,$ or any single value of $x$ at any other point between $t_1$ and $t_3$ (other than at $t_2$) would be sufficient to determine the function.